# How to plot only large communities/clusters in R

Tags: r, igraph

I have an igraph in `g`. Since the graph is huge I only want to plot communities with more than `10` members, but I want to plot them all in one plot.
My idea to remove unwanted elements is:

```
g <- delete_vertices(g, V(g)[igraph::clusters(g)$csize < 10])
```

but for some reason this plots a lot of single nodes, which is the opposite of what I try to achieve. Can you tell me where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is great, but the problem is that

```
igraph::clusters(g)$csize < 10
```

only returns a logical vector of clusters containing fewer than 10 members. Meanwhile, you need to know which vertices belong to those clusters.

Hence, we may proceed as follows.

```
set.seed(1)
g1 <- erdos.renyi.game(100, 1 / 70)
cls <- clusters(g1)
cls$csize
#  [1]  1  1 43  2 11  1  1  1  2  1  2  5  1  1  4  4  1  1  1  1  2  1  2  1
# [25]  4  1  1  1  1  1 # Two clusters of interest
g2 <- delete_vertices(g1, V(g1)[cls$membership %in% which(cls$csize <= 10)])
plot(g2)
```

[image]

Comment: can you please explain what you did here? how many total clusters were produced? how would you just plot one of these cluters?

Comment: I posted a question regarding your answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65016504/r-plot-larger-components-clarifying-another-stackoverflow-post   thank you